# Android APP cant build because of httpcore

Tags: java, android, jar

I am getting this error when I build my android app on my Machine, it runs perfectly on my old latptop/android enviroment , I get this error. Please let me know, if you need me to show more codes.

Old laptop is running one Android 1.2.2
Gradle 2.2.1 ??

my machine runs on 2.1.1
Gradle 2.10.0

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ahmad\AndroidStudioProjects\AMHAPP\app\build\intermediates\libs3\httpcore-4.3.jar
> ```
>
> (The system cannot find the path specified)

OR

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ahmad\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApp.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\lib\jcifs-1.3.18.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)

**Note: the following for the build paths of android studio**

Example:

old machine : 
compile files('C:/Users/Administrator/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp/.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts/lib/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')

new machine:
compile files('C:/Users/Ahmad/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp/.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts/lib/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "AMH.Code.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
android.packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile     files('C:/Users/Ahmad/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp/.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts/lib/jcifs-1.3.18.jar')
compile files('build/libs2/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('build/intermediates/libs3/httpcore-4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile     files('C:/Users/Ahmad/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp/.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts/lib/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
compile     files('C:/Users/Ahmad/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp/.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts/lib/libs2/apache-commons-net.jar')
compile     files('C:/Users/Ahmad/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp/.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts/lib/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile files('libs/core-2.2.jar')
compile files('C:/Users/Ahmad/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp/.gradle/2.2.1/taskArtifacts/lib/libs2/zbar.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'announce'
```

Comment: does C:\Users\Ahmad\AndroidStudioProjects\AMHAPP\app\build\intermediates\libs3\httpcore-4.3.jar exist on your latest machine? would be clear if you could share the build.gradle

Comment: add your 'http-core.jar' to **libs** folder of your project

Comment: I have added i jar file called httpcore.jar  , then there is new error for httpcore-4.3.jar  I added that aswell and still getting the second error
app->libs    droping in that folder

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ahmad\AndroidStudioProjects\GuardTourApp\app\build\intermediates\libs3\httpcore-4.3.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: why you are adding libraries like this?? There are simpler method then this. Why to complicate thing with so many paths??

Comment: my aplogies janki , I dont have any previous experience with android...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this to your build.gradle

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

}

Comment: after adding that        android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
.
.
.
}
now it shows me error Unable to find optional library org.apache.http.legacy

Comment: use this   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

Answer (score 0):

Either download jar for httpcore from here : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2
and add to your lib package and right click and add it as library

or

add gradle dependency in your gradle dependencies{} tag by adding : 
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'

and sync project.

Comment: after following your tips I got this error 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Ahmad\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApp\.gradle\2.2.1\taskArtifacts\lib\jcifs-1.3.18.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: I can find jcifs-1.3.18 as folder not jar

Comment: I changed the .zip to .jar and added it , However httpcore-4.3.jar came back again

Comment: I am not getting what is the current status of your problem. please tell me about it so that i can help further.

Comment: as I state in my thread , I simply moved a project from machine to another , then i start having issues with gradle which i fixed by using the recommended gradle then when i build the project I get **either** , jcifis-1.3.18  or httpcore-4.3.jar (The System cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Download jcifis from this link : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcifs/jcifs/1.3.17
and rebuilt your application.